# how to create multi array in foreach CI without loop all

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I have a problem from foreach to array why is everything loop?

example output json i want.

```
{"page":"books","list":[{"title":"ABC"},{ "title" : "CDE"}]}
```

example output from my code

```
{"page":"books","list":[{"title":"ABC"}]}{"page":"books","list":[{"title":"CDE"}]}
```

this my code

```
foreach ($row as $rows) :
        $arrayName = array(
            'page' => $this->input->get('type', TRUE),
            'list' => array([
                'title' => $rows['title'],
            ])
        );
        echo json_encode($arrayName);
endforeach;
```

and this my CI_Controller

```
return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

how to loop only in "**list :**" line only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't encode in every loop iteration, create your array in the format you want and then encode it to json.

```
$arrayName = [];
$arrayName['page'] = $this->input->get('type', TRUE);
foreach ($row as $rows) :  
        $arrayName['list'][] = [
                'title' => $rows['title']
            ];
endforeach;
        echo json_encode($arrayName);
```

In the above code you create your array and the static field `page` outside of the loop, you don't need it inside the loop.

The field that includes nested arrays is the `list` so you basically create nested arrays with key title and title value for each iteration.

When you are done you simply encode your overall array and you will end up with your expected output

Comment: OMG this really helped me. thanks for the help, I'm not experienced in playing json as there are many versions of each json output. thanks bro

Comment: Glad i helped :)